# Считать hash из атрибута модели Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 5.2
Ruby 2.5.2

При создании объекта http-запроса я сохраняю хэш параметров запроса в базу данных.

Сохраненный результат в базе выглядит примерно так (в виде строки):

`{"group_id"=>1111111, "user_id"=>1111111, "access_token"=>"1111111", "usr"=>#<User id: 1, email: "change@me-1523784-1111111.com", created_at: "2019-05-09 07:44:02", updated_at: "2019-05-09 07:44:54", name: "1111111 1111111", vk_offline_token: "1111111...", vk_admin: true, is_admin: true, vkid: 1111111>, "v"=>5.92}`

Затем мне требуется считать некоторые паарметры из этого хэша, однако я не могу более преобразовать эту строку обратно в хэш:

```
eval(captcha_to_edit.request_response.params)
```

Ошибка:

```
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
...alid_vk_user: true>, "v"=>5.92}
...                               ^
```

JSON.parse c соответствуюющим преобразованием строки также не отрабатывает.

Мне кажется, что проблема в сохраненной в хэше модели (ключ 'usr').

Сейчас я уже добавил к модели `serialize :params, Hash`, это должно помочь в будущем с корректным считыванием хэша, однако что мне делать сейчас?

Какой есть способ корректно считать данный хэш из строки? 
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Answer (score -1):

Проблему решил сам вырезанием из хэша параметра 'usr' с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
  param_str = @object_to_edit.request_response.params
  rr_params = param_str.gsub(/"usr(.*?)>,/, '')
  rr_params = eval(rr_params)
```

Comment: На so подобное обычно не считается ответом: нет кода, это скорее расценивается как комментарий. Да и даже если вам это помогло, то тут надо сказать, что ответ так себе: парсить json регулярками - моветон и костыли.

Comment: Было нужно в рамках исправления данных. Если бы изначально сделал `serialize :params, Hash`, то ничего подобного бы не понадобилось. Ответ будет полезен тем, кто "подпортил" данные схожим образом.